# Grouping LocalDateTime objects with startTIme and endTime using Java

Tags: java, java-8, java-time

I want to implement a grouping algorithm to group this List into minute intervals.

Example list:

```
List<Item> items = Arrays.asList(
    new Item(LocalDateTime.parse("2020-08-21T00:00:00"), LocalDateTime.parse("2020-08-21T00:02:00"), "item1"),
    new Item(LocalDateTime.parse("2020-08-21T00:01:00"), LocalDateTime.parse("2020-08-21T00:03:00"), "item2"),
    new Item(LocalDateTime.parse("2020-08-21T00:03:00"), LocalDateTime.parse("2020-08-21T00:07:00"), "item3"),
    new Item(LocalDateTime.parse("2020-08-21T00:08:00"), LocalDateTime.parse("2020-08-21T00:12:00"), "item4"),
    new Item(LocalDateTime.parse("2020-08-21T09:50:37"), LocalDateTime.parse("2020-08-21T09:56:49"), "item5"),
    new Item(LocalDateTime.parse("2020-08-21T09:59:37"), LocalDateTime.parse("2020-08-21T10:02:37"), "item6"),
    new Item(LocalDateTime.parse("2020-08-21T09:49:37"), LocalDateTime.parse("2020-08-21T09:51:37"), "item7"),
    new Item(LocalDateTime.parse("2019-12-31T23:59:37"), LocalDateTime.parse("2020-01-01T00:03:37"), "item8"),
    new Item(LocalDateTime.parse("2020-01-01T00:04:37"), LocalDateTime.parse("2020-01-01T00:06:37"), "item9")
);
```

Item class :

```
class Item {
    LocalDateTime startTime;
    LocalDateTime endTime;
    String name;

    // constructor etc
}
```

For simplicity, I will only refer to minutes but dates also matter. Given an interval of 5 minutes `00:00 - 00:02` can be grouped to the group of range `00:00 - 00:05` while `00:03 - 00:07` can possibly be grouped to two groups `00:00 - 00:05` and `00:05 - 00:10`.

Desired output for the above example list (names inluced only for readability output should contain the whole Item object):

```
{
    [item1, item2, item3],
    [item3, item4],
    [item5, item6],
    [item7, item5],
    [item8, item9]
}
```

Is it possible to do such grouping using a method like [Collectors#groupingBy](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy(java.util.function.Function))?

**Edit*** To avoid negative comments I added my "non-efficient" solution in the answers.

Comment: How is it different from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63507920/grouping-localdatetime-objects-in-intervals-using-java-8?

Comment: The difference is that this question's item object has startTime and endTime so the grouping should be made with 2 criteria instead of one. The question you are referring to has a function given to groupBy that returns a single the group that LocalDateTime objects belong. In this question, an Item can belong to two different groups based on startTime and endTime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A short answer to the main question:

> *Is it possible to do such grouping using a method like Collectors#groupingBy?*

is **yes**.

As mentioned in the comments, main issue with this task is that a single item cannot be "grouped" into a single entry in general case, but it needs to be multiplexed into several entries depending on both `startTime` and `endTime`.

Possibly, more than two 5-minute ranges can be used, for example: `startTime: 00:02; endTime: 00:12` will cover three ranges: `00:00-00:05`, `00:05-00:10`, `00:10-00:15` -- this case is updated for `item4`.

That being said, the following solution can be offered:

```java
import java.time.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.*;

public class Solution {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        List<Item> items = Arrays.asList(
            new Item(LocalDateTime.parse("2020-08-21T00:00:00"), LocalDateTime.parse("2020-08-21T00:02:00"), "item1"),
            new Item(LocalDateTime.parse("2020-08-21T00:01:00"), LocalDateTime.parse("2020-08-21T00:03:00"), "item2"),
            new Item(LocalDateTime.parse("2020-08-21T00:03:00"), LocalDateTime.parse("2020-08-21T00:07:00"), "item3"),
            new Item(LocalDateTime.parse("2020-08-21T00:04:00"), LocalDateTime.parse("2020-08-21T00:12:00"), "item4"),
            new Item(LocalDateTime.parse("2020-08-21T09:50:37"), LocalDateTime.parse("2020-08-21T09:56:49"), "item5"),
            new Item(LocalDateTime.parse("2020-08-21T09:59:37"), LocalDateTime.parse("2020-08-21T10:02:37"), "item6"),
            new Item(LocalDateTime.parse("2020-08-21T09:49:37"), LocalDateTime.parse("2020-08-21T09:51:37"), "item7"),
            new Item(LocalDateTime.parse("2019-12-31T23:59:37"), LocalDateTime.parse("2020-01-01T00:03:37"), "item8"),
            new Item(LocalDateTime.parse("2020-01-01T00:04:37"), LocalDateTime.parse("2020-01-01T00:06:37"), "item9"),
            // added to test a single entry within 5 min range
            new Item(LocalDateTime.parse("2020-01-01T00:42:37"), LocalDateTime.parse("2020-01-01T00:44:37"), "item10")
        );
        
        items.stream()
             .flatMap(Solution::convert)
             .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(x -> x.getKey(), LinkedHashMap::new, Collectors.mapping(x -> x.getValue(), Collectors.toList())))
             .values()
             .forEach(System.out::println);
    }
    
    public static Stream<Map.Entry<LocalDateTime, Item>> convert(Item item) {
        LocalDateTime start = getKey(item.getStartTime());
        LocalDateTime end = getKey(item.getEndTime()).plusMinutes(5);
        
        return Stream
                .iterate(start, d -> d.isBefore(end), d -> d.plusMinutes(5))
                .map(d -> Map.entry(d, item));
                    
    }

    public static LocalDateTime getKey(LocalDateTime time) {
        return LocalDateTime.of(time.getYear(), time.getMonthValue(), time.getDayOfMonth(), time.getHour(), time.getMinute() - time.getMinute() % 5);
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
[item1, item2, item3, item4]
[item3, item4]
[item4]
[item5, item7]
[item5, item6]
[item6]
[item7]
[item8]
[item8, item9]
[item9]
[item10]
```

*Note*

Some Java 9 features are used in the code snippet:

- [Map.entry](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#entry-K-V-)
- [Stream.iterate with predicate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#iterate-T-java.util.function.Predicate-java.util.function.UnaryOperator-)

**Update**

Java 9 features can be replaced with the following Java 8 compatible code:

- `Map.entry -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry`
- use Java 8 `iterate` + `limit(ChronoUnit.MINUTES.between(start, end) / 5)`

```
public static Stream<Map.Entry<String, Item>> convert(Item item) {
    LocalDateTime start = getKey(item.getStartTime());
    LocalDateTime end = getKey(item.getEndTime()).plusMinutes(5);
        
    return Stream
            .iterate(start, d -> d.plusMinutes(5))
            .limit(ChronoUnit.MINUTES.between(start, end) / 5)
            .map(d -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry(d + "**" + d.plusMinutes(5), item));
}
```

If resulting values are filtered to contain valueat least two items, the result is as follows:

```java
// ...
        .entrySet()
        .stream()
        .filter(x -> x.getValue().size() > 1)
        .forEach(System.out::println);
```

**Output**

```
2020-08-21T00:00**2020-08-21T00:05=[item1, item2, item3, item4]
2020-08-21T00:05**2020-08-21T00:10=[item3, item4]
2020-08-21T09:50**2020-08-21T09:55=[item5, item7]
2020-08-21T09:55**2020-08-21T10:00=[item5, item6]
2020-01-01T00:00**2020-01-01T00:05=[item8, item9]
```

[Online demo](https://ideone.com/irSgpJ)

Comment: @Michael, Well, this is all outsourcing/outstaffing biz is about, and that's what I do for living -- creating tasks in customers' JIRA and resolving them.  So I would accept your generous offer but I'm sure that you wouldn't mean it, because I'm not the best There are better guys such as [Jacob G](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7294647/jacob-g) and [WJS](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1552534/wjs) who dared to answer [the previous non-elaborated question by the OP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63507920/grouping-localdatetime-objects-in-intervals-using-java-8)

Comment: Appreciate the answer sadly using Java 9 is not an option for me @AlexRudenko

Comment: I can't see the reason behind all these negative comments. There are tons of questions here on stackoverflow that ask for a direct answer to a problem without including a "progress" snippet. I have posted my original "non-efficient" answer to this problem below.

Comment: @ThanosM, I provided the update to replace Java 9 features with appropriate Java 8 compatible code

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Item> items = Arrays.asList(
        new Item(LocalDateTime.parse("2020-08-21T00:00:00"), LocalDateTime.parse("2020-08-21T00:02:00"), "item1"),
        new Item(LocalDateTime.parse("2020-08-21T00:01:00"), LocalDateTime.parse("2020-08-21T00:03:00"), "item2"),
        new Item(LocalDateTime.parse("2020-08-21T00:03:00"), LocalDateTime.parse("2020-08-21T00:07:00"), "item3"),
        new Item(LocalDateTime.parse("2020-08-21T00:08:00"), LocalDateTime.parse("2020-08-21T00:12:00"), "item4"),
        new Item(LocalDateTime.parse("2020-08-21T09:50:37"), LocalDateTime.parse("2020-08-21T09:56:49"), "item5"),
        new Item(LocalDateTime.parse("2020-08-21T09:59:37"), LocalDateTime.parse("2020-08-21T10:02:37"), "item6"),
        new Item(LocalDateTime.parse("2020-08-21T09:49:37"), LocalDateTime.parse("2020-08-21T09:51:37"), "item7"),
        new Item(LocalDateTime.parse("2019-12-31T23:59:37"), LocalDateTime.parse("2020-01-01T00:03:37"), "item8"),
        new Item(LocalDateTime.parse("2020-01-01T00:04:37"), LocalDateTime.parse("2020-01-01T00:06:37"), "item9")
    );

    Map<String, List<Item>> groups = new HashMap<>();

    items.stream().forEach(item -> {
        int startTimeMinute = item.startTime.getMinute();

        int startTimeMinutesOver = startTimeMinute % 5;

        int endTimeMinute = item.endTime.getMinute();

        int endTimeMinutesOver = endTimeMinute % 5;

        LocalDateTime firstGroupStartTime = item.startTime.truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.MINUTES).withMinute(startTimeMinute - startTimeMinutesOver);
        LocalDateTime secondGroupStartTime = item.endTime.truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.MINUTES).withMinute(endTimeMinute - endTimeMinutesOver);

        // check if item belongs to a single or more groups
        if (firstGroupStartTime.equals(secondGroupStartTime)) {
            String groupRange = firstGroupStartTime.toString() + "**" + firstGroupStartTime.plusMinutes(5).toString();

            groups.computeIfAbsent(groupRange, s -> new ArrayList<>()).add(item);
        } else {
            String firstGroupRange = firstGroupStartTime.toString() + "**" + firstGroupStartTime.plusMinutes(5).toString();
            groups.computeIfAbsent(firstGroupRange, s -> new ArrayList<>()).add(item);

            String secondGroupRange = secondGroupStartTime.toString() + "**" + secondGroupStartTime.plusMinutes(5).toString();
            groups.computeIfAbsent(secondGroupRange, s -> new ArrayList<>()).add(item);
        }
    });

    // remove groups that contain only a single item
    groups.entrySet().removeIf(stringListEntry -> stringListEntry.getValue().size() == 1);

    for (String key : groups.keySet()) {
        System.out.println(String.format("%s %s", key, groups.get(key).stream().map(item -> item.name).collect(Collectors.toList())));
    }
}
```

Output

```
2020-08-21T00:05**2020-08-21T00:10 [item3, item4]
2020-08-21T00:00**2020-08-21T00:05 [item1, item2, item3]
2020-08-21T09:50**2020-08-21T09:55 [item5, item7]
2020-01-01T00:00**2020-01-01T00:05 [item8, item9]
2020-08-21T09:55**2020-08-21T10:00 [item5, item6]
```

The main reason for my original question was to find a proper and more efficient way of doing that. Reiterating over groups to remove single groups is not the best thing to do considering that I would have a lot of groups.